# Retrieve values by matching array

Tags: javascript

The values of the checked checkboxes are crossmatched with the array to fileter results. How can I pick the `price` and `lot` values?

```js
var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("fruits"); 
const item = [
{"lychee":{ price:10, lot:8}}, 
{"orange" :{ price:12, lot:6}},
{"apple" :{ price:8, lot:3}},
{"mango"  :{ price:12, lot:5}},
{"banana" :{ price:4, lot:1}}];
    
var checked = [...inputElements].map(item => { 
  if(item.checked){ 
    return item.value
   }
}).filter(item => item);

console.log(checked);
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="lychee" checked>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="orange">
```

Comment: what do you mean you want to "pick" the price and lot? Also your filter() is not doing anything.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56173440/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] with clear input and expected output

Comment: @GifCo Thanks. I am trying to cross match the checked checkboxes against the array. Based on that I am trying to retrieve the price and lot values from the array. Not sure if this is a good approach. All I want to achieve is to match the checked checkboxes against an array to get the price and a lot value. `console.log(checked)` returns the checked values (eg. mango, lychee ...)

Comment: And please:  `var checked = document.querySelectorAll("[name=fruit]:checked").map(chk => chk.value)`

Comment: @mplungjan [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vpa9q53o/) is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelectorAll with a proper selector will give you the checked values:

Note I changed from Array of objects to a plain object

```js
const item = { 
  "lychee": {"price": 10,"lot": 8},
  "orange": {"price": 12,"lot": 6},
  "apple":  {"price": 8, "lot": 3},
  "mango":  {"price": 12,"lot": 5},
  "banana": {"price": 4, "lot": 1}
};
let res = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=fruits]:checked")]
             .map(chk => `${chk.value},lot:${item[chk.value].lot}, price:${item[chk.value].price}`);
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res.join("<br/>");
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="lychee" checked> lychee <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="orange"> orange <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="banana" checked> banana <br />
<br/>
<span id="res"></span>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks mplungjan +10

Comment: @jules2x added a template for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll(".fruits:checked")` to get all checked elements with class `.fruits`. Make a `Set` object with its values.

Use `filter` to filter the `item` array.

```js
var checked = new Set(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".fruits:checked")).map(o => o.value));
const item = [{"lychee":{"price":10,"lot":8}},{"orange":{"price":12,"lot":6}},{"apple":{"price":8,"lot":3}},{"mango":{"price":12,"lot":5}},{"banana":{"price":4,"lot":1}}];

let result = item.filter(o => checked.has(Object.keys(o)[0]));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<input class="fruits" type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="lychee" checked> lychee <br />
<input class="fruits" type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="orange"> orange <br />
<input class="fruits" type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="banana" checked> banana <br />
```

Comment: or `document.querySelectorAll("[name=fruit]:checked")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mplungjan :)

Comment: Happy to hep :)

Answer (score 0):

Use filter to get the checked values.

Then map the array and take only the values of each object element.

```
var checked = [...inputElements].filter(inputElement => inputElement.checked);
var valuesOfChecked = checked.map(item => [Object.values(item)[0].price,Object.values(item)[0].lot])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change you structure

```js
var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("fruits"); 
const items = {
"lychee" :{ price:10, lot:8}, 
"orange" :{ price:12, lot:6},
"apple" :{ price:8, lot:3},
"mango"  :{ price:12, lot:5},
"banana" :{ price:4, lot:1}};
    
let prices = [...inputElements].filter(elem => elem.checked).map(elem => items[elem.value]);

console.log(prices);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="lychee" checked>
 <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="orange">
```

Comment: No need to filter. Just use a proper selector - see my answer

Comment: @mplungjan Depend if he also need other inputs. In this case filter would be faster than doing another dom query

Comment: Oh ok got what you meant ! But here difference of time doesn't come from exactly from filter but from the fast you write numbers while i write dom elements